# Do two finite groups of the same order have composition series of the same length?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If I have two finite groups $H$ and $G$ where $|G| = |H|$, my guess will be that their composition series don't necessarily have the same length. But I'm not able to find a counterexample. Where should I search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about $S_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}/{120\mathbb{Z}}$?

Or even easier, $A_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z}$. Take any non-abelian simple group $G$ so its composition series has length one, and then compare that to the length of the composition series of the cyclic group of size $|G|$.